# Can one model fluid flow only by using the convection–diffusion equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, diffusion, convection

Modeling fluid flow in a coil seems very complicated, especially for turbulent flow. Having Navier-Stokes equations seems to be the right way to go, but I was wondering... can one use the convection-diffusion equation?

$$
\rho C_p \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\rho C_p \vec{u} \nabla T - \nabla \cdot (-k \nabla T) = 0
$$

If one would assume that the velocity in a coil is 5 m/s in all directions and doesn't change (I know this is a stretch), what would be the limitations of such a model? I'm trying to model cooling of a metal by a coil and having flow equations is too complicated at this point :-) In theory, it should be fine, since such an equation considers the transport of a substance or quantity by bulk motion.

EDIT: The system would look like this:
[image]

The cold side has a constant hot temperature BC which is 25K lower than the initial temperature of the entire system, so the hot side should take the heat from the metal matrix and release it in the hot side. All the other sides are insulated.

Comment: This really needs some elaboration, IMO. Is the coil running through the metal or is the metal running through the coil?

Comment: Added a sketch. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the sketch. Is the metal solid, like an engine block?

Comment: The broad answer is -- you can use any model you want to for something, but will it be useful? What are the quantities of interest you're after and what tolerances do you need to get within? Just looking for trends, or orders of magnitude, or would 1% error mean your hardware breaks and the company goes out of business?

Comment: I would like to see relative trends. I want to check how the number of lines in the coil affects the heat transfer. As for the metal solid, it could be aluminum, as in an engine block.

Comment: @tpg2114, thanks for confirming. But what would be the limitations? Would it be very far from modeling it using Navier-Stokes at that velocity? I'm guessing that a turbulent flow would be far, but a laminar flow closer to a model that uses diffusion-convection.

Comment: *I'm guessing that a turbulent flow would be far, but a laminar flow closer to a model that uses diffusion-convection* No. Whether flow is laminar or turbulent doesn't depend on what model you use. Turbulent flow is easier to handle in the case of heat transfer, generally speaking. And in industrial conditions, turbulence is more prevalent.

Comment: Agree. So you also think that the laminar flow would be fine to model with this equation, right? I know that turbulence would make it more realistic, but I can't afford that right now.

Comment: Frankly speaking, the equation that models the temperature inside the fluid, using *laminar* flow is HORRENDOUS. Very hard to solve, indeed. And then we haven't even begun to model heat conduction through the metal matrix!

Comment: So the first simplification is to assume turbulent flow in the coil, absolutely!

Comment: Thank you for all your input!